How can I access configuration from WebApplicationFactory ConfigureTestServices?
I setup some integration tests using WebApplicationFactory but I'm having trouble overriding some services in the ConfigureTestServices method.
This is my WebApplicationFactory:
public class TestWebApplicationFactory: WebApplicationFactory<Program> 
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(s =>
        {
                 // Here I would like to access IConfiguration              
                 var configuration = ....?

                 //and then use some values from configuration, while overriding others with some fixed test values             
                services.ConfigureMyService(new MyOptions           
                {
                    Option1 = config.Option1,
                    Option2 = "new-fixed-value",
                    ... other options           
                });
        });
    } 
}

This is my production startup:
public static class StartupExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        var config = configuration.Get<MyConfig>();
        services.AddSingleton(config);

        services.ConfigureMyService(new MyOptions
        {
            Option1 = config.Option1,
            Option2 = config.Option2,
            ... other options
        });
    }
}

public class MyOptions
{
        public string Option1{ get; set; }
        public string Option2{ get; set; }
}

The service I'm trying to override is added to DI in an external package I don't have access to. MyService visibility is Internal, so it cannot be referenced/overridden directly from WebApplicationFactory. The only way to override it is to call again the ConfigureMyService method:
// Defined in an external package I don't have access to. MyService visibility is Internal, so it cannot be referenced/overridden
private static void ConfigureMyService(this IServiceCollection services, MyOptions options)
{
    var someService = new MyService(options.Option1, options.Option2);
    
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>(someService);
}

I suppose I could build the service provider inside ConfigureTestServices and get MyOptions through that (s.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<MyOptions >()) but that's definitely a smell and I'd like to avoid that.

Can you use the Services property of WebApplicationFactory. e.g. var configuration = Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();?

No, accessing the Services property from inside ConfigureWebHost causes a recursive call to ConfigureWebHost, resulting in an infinite loop.

You should lazily configure the dependency with a factory method, rather than giving it the instance directly:
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB>(serviceProvider =>
    {
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyOptions>();
        // Do your customization...
        return MyFakeDynamoClient(configuration);
    });
});


Hi Martin, thanks for the answer. I had an extra line in the original post (regarding IAmazonDb) hich could have misled you, sorry. I have now removed it.
Unfortunately I cannot go that way since I need to call the external package ConfigureMyService method. What I want to override is MyService, but its visibility is Internal, so it cannot be referenced/overridden directly from WebApplicationFactory

In that case my suggestions would be to do one of the following:

Change those types to be public so you can access them;
Use InternalsVisibleTo to allow your tests access to internal types
Use an in-memory configuration source to override the configuration options similar to how settings can be overridden with environment variables and JSON configuration files (assuming your internal service is configurable that way)


Option 1 and 2 are not applicable, that's an external package I have no control over. Option 3 neither would work, that internal service is only configurable via calling the ConfigureMyService.
What I'm trying to achieve here is getting access to my appsettings.json (or IConfiguration) from the ConfigureTestServices method without overriding those.

If you can't refactor the code or lazily initialize with access to IServiceProvider, then I think your only option is what you suggested in your original post, and call BuildServiceProvider() to get an intermediate service provider to use to bootstrap things.
